# How can I kill process, which has spawned a child using system()?

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, process, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7 (though the same problem could perhaps also apply to a native Linux environment).

A parent process - which happens to be a Ruby program, but I guess the same problem would occur, if this were a pure C application - uses `system()` to execute an external (possibly long-running) command.

While this external program is running, the parent process gets killed. The child process is still alive. What can I do to ensure, that the child process gets killed too?

Here a "sandbox" scenario to explain the problem: In one terminal window, I execute the following command:

```
ruby -e 'puts $$; system("sh")' # Could also be a C program
```

Clearly, this hangs forever on the `sh` command, after having printed the process id.

Now I try from a different terminal window

```
kill -INT ...
```

to kill the Ruby process. Using procps or ps, I can verify that this process is still alive. Now I use

```
kill -TERM ....
```

Still, the process doesn't get killed. Finally I do a

```
kill -KILL ....
```

and of course, this does the job. The Ruby process is killed, but the child process ('sh') is still alive.

I understand that this is expected behaviour, but what is an easy and reliable workaround?

I tried to establish a session and called `Process.setsid` before executing `system`, but I get the error message

*`setsid': Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)*

Maybe `setsid` is not available on Cygwin, which would not surprise me, because the Windows process handling is very different.

Any other ideas, what I could try? BTW, the code is supposed to be ported to Linux eventually, so if possible, I would like to use a solution which runs under Cygwin and Linux alike.

Comment: did you try `killall -9 ruby`  ?

Comment: Oh my God! This would kill all my Ruby processes!!! Neither a solution for my problem (since it would kill only the parent process and not its child, and it would also kill all other Ruby processes spawned from a Cygwin shell!

Comment: The generic solution in Windows is to put the child into a job object.  Whether you can sensibly do that via ruby/cygwin I don't know.

Comment: .... and the question is, to what extent the job object solution would run on Linux. It doesn't sound very portable.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](http://ujihisa.blogspot.be/2010/03/how-to-run-external-command.html) marvelous blog about asynchronous processing in Ruby, it suggests to use fork in Linux and spawn in Windows, I suggest trying both in Cygwin

```
pid = fork do
  exec 'sleep', '10'
end
Process.kill pid
```

Comment: I was thinking about this. Using this approach, I would have to store the process id of the child (variable pid in your example) somewhere, so that the killer process can fetch it. I just have hoped that a solution where I can use `system` for forking the child, would be possible...